# Design complexity with subclassing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, subclassing

I'm using Cocos2D for iOS, but you most likely don't have to be familiar with Cocos2D, just Obj-C to answer my question.

I have an enemy class while developing this game that I've used for a long time, but now it's reached a point of complexity and I'll need to do something about to make it more organized and readable.

The way it works currently is this: I have the enemy class that I allocate a certain number of times and insert into a mutable array. I can then flip through that mutable array whenever.  When the enemy class is allocated, it is also directed to initialize and pass a string of the enemy name.  In it's init there are a series of if/if else statements that check the enemy name and set the right values for it.  This worked just fine, except design-wise it got very confusing to look through all those names when I added more and more enemies.

What I want to do now is subclass off of my enemy class of all the different enemies. I'll need to access the enemy's properties just like I would other kinds of enemies from that class.

Right now in the enemy class init I have something like:

```
-(id) initWithEnemy:(NSString *)kind {

    if([kind isEqualToString:@"enemyName"]){

    //set values

    }
    else if([kind isEqualToString:@"anotherEnemyName"]){

    //set values

    }

    //etc, etc..

}
```

Now I want to have this set values stuff happen in other files.  One, or a set of header/main files for each enemy.  So inside initWithEnemy, I was thinking maybe I could allocate an enemy name class from the "kind" string that's passed.  Not sure if I could use NSClassFromString. I've experimented with it a bit, but I'm not really sure how to access the class properties the way I did before. Even if I did access the properties the same way I did before, does that mean all the enemy name classes will have to have all the same amount of properties?

Comment: Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your enemies into an abstract base class with concrete sub-classes - that is a good approach. Be mindful though, that it can often be better to use composition over inheritance - this is where you inject objects into a holder class to model something. Otherwise you might run into the problem where you have an enemy that's both a 'Monster' and a 'Wizard' and the single inheritance chain doesn't allow that.

There are two design patterns that seem appropriate here - they both focus on decoupling complex instantiation rules from the class itself. One is ***the factory pattern*** and the other is ***the builder pattern***. If you split into a class hierarchy the former will be appropriate, otherwise the latter.

Sorry, can't provide more examples - writing this on an iPad, and on the way out the door.

Comment: This is a lot of information to digest, but it seems very useful. I'll need to work through it bit by bit. Thank you.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - perfect. . . can't ask for much more than that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Instead of strings, declare an `enum`

   ```
   typedef enum {
       kEnemyInvalid = 0,
       kEnemyName1,
       kEnemyName2,
       [...]
   } EnemyType;
   ```
2. Create an `Enemy` class with the global properties for all enemy types.
3. Create necessary enemy subclasses for each type. It's possible that a class will cover more than one enemy types.
4. Create a function (possibly a class method)

   ```
   Class EnemyClassFromEnemyType(EnemyType type) {
       switch (type) {
           case kEnemyName1:
              return [EnemyName1 class];
           case kEnemyName2:
              return [EnemyName2 class];
           default:
              return Nil;
       }
   }
   ```

   This function makes a connection between the enemy type and the class that implements it. There are ways how to make it more pretty, my preferred way is using X-Macros.
5. And now let's create a factory method to create the enemies

   ```
   + (Enemy*)createEnemyWithType:(EnemyType*)enemyType {
       Class enemyClass = EnemyClassFromEnemyType(enemyType);
       return [[enemyClass alloc] initWithType:enemyType];
   }
   ```

**The same using X-Macros**

Header file

```
#define ENEMY_DEFINITIONS \
  ENEMY_DEFINITION(kEnemyInvalid, = 0, Nil) \
  ENEMY_DEFINITION(kEnemyName1,, [EnemyName1 class]) \
  ENEMY_DEFINITION(kEnemyName2,, [EnemyName2 class])

#define ENEMY_DEFINITION(name, intValue, enemyClass) name intValue, 

/**
 * Your enum declaration.
 */
typedef enum {
    ENEMY_DEFINITIONS
} EnemyType;

#undef ENEMY_DEFINITION

Class EnemyClassFromEnemyType(EnemyType type);
NSString* NSStringFromEnemyType(EnemyType type);
```

Implementation file

```
#define ENEMY_DEFINITION(name, intValue, enemyClass) [name] = @#name,

NSString* EnemyTypeStringTable[] = {
    ENEMY_DEFINITIONS
}

#undef ENEMY_DEFINITION

NSString* NSStringFromEnemyType(EnemyType type) {
    return EnemyTypeStringTable[type]
}

#define ENEMY_DEFINITION(name, intValue, enemyClass) classTable[name] = enemyClass;

Class EnemyClassFromEnemyType(EnemyType type) {
    static Class* classTable = nil;

    if (classTable == nil) {
        classTable = malloc(sizeof(Class) * sizeof(EnemyTypeStringTable) / sizeof(NSString*));

        ENEMY_DEFINITIONS
    }

    return classTable[type];
}

#undef ENEMY_DEFINITION
```

The beauty of using X-Macros technique is that you have everything in one place, you can easily add more types without changing anything else. You get something like Java enums because the enums can have properties.

Comment: Thanks, this is a suggestion I got earlier too. I'll need to do a lot of replacing NSStrings to enums.

Comment: Step 4 and on kind of confuses me. Why do you mention that I can put a switch statement there? I can just pass my enemy type into the method I'm calling, right?

Comment: @VagueExplanation Explained the 4th step a bit more. This function is used by the factory method from step 5.

Comment: With step 4 you can just use NSClassFromString, right? That way you don't have to use a switch statement.

Comment: @VagueExplanation Technically, you can. However, not recommended from code quality perspective. What happens if you mistype a string? You get runtime error or , with obj-c, you will probably get some `nil` objects and a you will have to debug the problem. With this design, you'll get a compilation error. Also, sometimes you want to use the same class for different enemy types.